# Create a Portable Executable file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am creating a desktop application.

How to convert the whole project into a Single  .exe file?

Comment: Do a bit of research first and you will find the answer really quickly.

Comment: In short You want to create a portable setup

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to merge all the assemblies into your executable. I'd expect your icon to already be an embedded resource - or you should at least be able to create it as such.

Targeting .NET 2.0 would make the application more widely portable in that it would just work on machines which only have .NET 2.0 installed - but I don't know what the proportions look like for 2.0 vs 3.5 deployment, and more importantly they may well not be the same as the proportions for deployment out of your target audience.